# jQuery Toggle working in test but not working on implementation

Tags: jquery, toggle

I apologize for the noob question but I really can't find the solution to this.

I've got a link that when clicked toggle's a ul.

`$("#pastShows").click(function () {
  $(".shows").toggle("slow");
});`​

```
<h3 id="pastShows"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Past</a></h3>
<div class="shows">
  <ul>
    <li>Show 1</li>
    <li>Show 2</li>
    <li>Show 3</li>
    <li>Show 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

It works perfect in this fiddler. http://jsfiddle.net/Chadimoglou/NG8Dj/2/

But I can't get it to work when implemented here http://www.kiirstinmarilyn.com/#shows

Thank you kindly for the help.

Comment: You have several issues that can be seen in your console (check Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools) that may be causing your issue.  Either way, I'm not sure what needs to be clicked to trigger the toggle and what should be shown/hidden.

Comment: @zshooter  thanks for pointing the console out.  I've never really looked at it.  Interesting how something is pulling from the FB adserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue here's you are using `window.onload`, in place of the `document.ready()` or `$(function() {}`. jQuery’s `document.ready()` method gets called as soon as DOM is ready (means browser has parsed the HTML and built the DOM tree). If your web page has large images, it will not wait for loading of images completely. Hence it may called before `window.onload` method. We can have multiple `document.ready()` methods on a web page that will be called in coming sequence. On the other hand, `window.onload` method gets called when images and all associated resources of the page have been fully loaded. Suppose your web page has large size images then until all the images are not fully loaded on the page, `window.onload` method will not called.

So, just replace the code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    $("#pastShows").click(function () {
        $(".shows").toggle("slow");
    });
}
```

with:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#pastShows").click(function () {
      $(".shows").toggle("slow");
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Try getting rid of the window.onload and putting your initialization code in document.ready.

Replace this:

```
/*----Toggle past shows----*/
window.onload=function(){
    $("#pastShows").click(function () {
        $(".shows").toggle("slow");
        alert("It Worked");
    });
}
```

With this:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#pastShows").click(function () {
      $(".shows").toggle("slow");
      alert("It Worked");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank very much!  This worked perfectly.  Is there any reason why the former didn't work?